# Is this a run on sentence?

Tags: sentence-fragments, run-on-sentence

Me and my dad are having a dispute over if this is is a run on sentence or not:

> From making silly pictures on Photoshop to playing a game that brought me to another world, and even being dubbed as the IT guy in elementary school.

He argues that it's a run on, and the ending can't stand on it's own. I think otherwise. May anyone help settle this debate?

Comment: Also, it's "My dad and I", "the ending can't stand on its own" and "Can anyone help".

Answer (score 3):

If this isn't an answer to a question like "What was it that made you an IT whizz at an early age?", then the sentence is profoundly ungrammatical, and the argument over whether it is a run-on sentence is moot.

You would need something like: "From making silly pictures on Photoshop to playing a game that brought me to another world, (I was always fascinated by what computers could do), and (I was) even dubbed the IT guy in elementary school.".

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a fragment.  You have neither subject nor predicate.

Thus, you are correct that it's not a run on because you have less than one clause.  Your dad is correct that the ending can't stand on it's own because you have less than one clause.

So... you're both right?